# Accessing label address outside of function

Tags: c

I'm writing "threaded interpreter" using computed goto. How do I initialize address lookup table to be visible from different functions without additional runtime cost?

Label address is only visible at same function and static lookup table is initialized by compiler in data section without runtime cost at each call. But it's visible only in same function and I want to have another function to have access to it, for example to cache addresses and save lookups in main interpreter code. I can take pointer to this table and store it somewhere, but it will happen every time function is called, and it will get called frequently. Yes, it's just only one mov, but is there another way?

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void** table_ptr;

// how do i declare static variable and init it later once?


// Tried this. Generates runtime assigns at each call. Not unexpected
// static void** jumps_addr;

int main()
{
    // labels are visible only inside the function
    
    // generates runtime assigns at each call
    // jumps_addr = (void* [10]){

    // this initializes it in static data section, but name is only visible inside this function
    static void* jumps_addr[10] = {
      [1] =  &&operation_print,
        
    };


    // want another way instead of this
    table_ptr = jumps_addr;

    // not optimize this 
    volatile int opcode = 1;

    goto *jumps_addr[opcode];
    
    return 0;
    
    operation_print:;
        printf("hello\n");
        
    return 0;
}


void do_some_preprocessing_work(void){
    
    // want access to jumps_addr table here
    // without having to store it somewhere
    
    // [do something with table_ptr]

    // this is to prevent optimization to explore what compiler does on godbolt.org
    // because it will optimize away table_ptr entirely if not used
    volatile i = 1;
    i += table_ptr[i];
    
    //actual code here will store labbel addrs into opcode struct to save table lookup at runtime
    
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow what you're asking, but if you want your table initialized at compile time then its initial contents must be listed in an initializer in its declaration.

Comment: The problem is that I initialize table with &&label, which is not visible outside of function it's declared in, so I'm forced to place declaration and initialization inside that function, and this makes variable invisible from outside. I would like to work around this in some way if possible

Comment: Declare it in the function,  make it global,  or pass it to the function.   What other option is there?

Answer (score 0):

The solution might sound unorthodox, but how about not to use any functions, but only **goto**.

Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    volatile int opcode;

    static void* jumps_addr[10] = {
        [0] = &&do_some_preprocessing_work,
        [1] = &&operation_print
    };
    
    opcode = 0;
    goto *jumps_addr[opcode];
    
    return 1;
    
    
    
    operation_print:
    
    printf("hello\n");
        
    return 0;
    
    
    
    do_some_preprocessing_work:
    
    printf("jumps_addr[%i]\n", ++opcode);
    goto *jumps_addr[opcode];
    
    return 1;
}
```